# Having Toruble Dynamically Updating Data Table Using Jquery/JavaScript & XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, datatable, html-table

I am able to update the table but it's not behaving as it should example it should create pages and list total rows but it's not doing any of it.

[image: screenshot of issIe]

ajax call as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var sindex = 0, xUpdatedServices;
var parser, xmlDoc;
var sericeables = "";
var table = document.getElementById("example-checkbox");
var row;
var cell1;
var cell2;

function ServerServiceInfo() {
    // Validating input
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../Service/CallServer.asmx/ReadExecuteCmd',
        data: "{'As':'SystemCore', 'Aa':'-an','Oc':''}",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        beforeSend: function () { },
        complete: function () { },
        error: onError,
        success: services_linux
    });
}
```

The section which deals with inserting new rows

```
if (xUpdatedServices[sindex].getElementsByTagName("service_stat")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.indexOf('+') >= 0) {
        sericeables = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>Online';
    } else {
        sericeables = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Offline';
    }
    row = table.insertRow(1);
    cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = xUpdatedServices[sindex].getElementsByTagName("sname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    cell2.innerHTML = sericeables;
```

the ajax handler

```
 function services_linux(result) {

    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(result.d, "text/xml");
    xUpdatedServices = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CoreServices");
    sindex = 29;
    UpdateEach4Services(); 
}
```

Comment: Does the table have any Primary Keys.  When a table has a primary key, only one row will exist for each primary key.  It doesn't allow duplicates with same Primary key.  Also Insert will only work if the Primary key doesn't exist.  If the key already exists then you have to use Update instead of Insert.